Azure Cosmos DB for Mongo data consistency
I tried to implement the transactional outbox pattern in my Spring Boot app.
I'm using Azure CosmosDB for Mongo, which does not support transactions across collections.
When I attempted to perform such an operation, I received an error about the unsupported operation.
How should I approach data consistency in this situation?
Is there an equivalent option available?
Thank you in advance for your help!

can you add what you have tried and error if you are facing any error?

I added @Transactional on the method which performed operations on two collections.
I don't have exact response, it was related to Azure Cosmos DB for Mongo custom error. Because based on the info from Azure doc:
**Multi-document transactions are supported within an unsharded collection in API version 4.0. Multi-document transactions are not supported across collections or in sharded collections in 4.0. The timeout for transactions is a fixed 5 seconds.
All drivers that support wire protocol version 4.0 or greater will support Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB multi-document transactions.**
